# Openshift - Environment variable getting evaluated to hostname

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools, openshift-enterprise

I want to pass an environment variable that should get evaluated to the hostname of the running container. This is what I am trying to do

```
oc new-app -e DASHBOARD_PROTOCOL=http -e ADMIN_PASSWORD=abc@123 -e KEYCLOAK_URL=http://keycloak.openidp.svc:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_REALM=master -e DASHBOARD_HOSTNAME=$HOSTNAME -e GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=grafana-simple-json-datasource,michaeldmoore-annunciator-panel,briangann-gauge-panel,savantly-heatmap-panel,briangann-datatable-panel grafana/grafana:5.2.1
```

How to ensure that the DASHBOARD_HOSTNAME gets evaluated to the value of the hostname of the running container image

Comment: Use a custom start command for the deployment and you should be able to set ``DASHBOARD_HOSTNAME=$HOSTNAME`` there and then execute the original start command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For take the hostname value from a pod you could use the metadata.name.
follow the eg:

```
  env:
    - name: HOSTNAME
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: metadata.name
```

Answer (score 0):

After creating the application, you could edit the deployment config (`oc edit dc/<deployment_config>`) or [patch it](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/cli_reference/basic_cli_operations.html#patch) to configure the `DASHBOARD_HOSTNAME` environment variable using the [Downward API](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/downward_api.html#dapi-consuming-container-values).

This may be a personal preference but as much as `oc new-app` is convenient I'd rather work with ([declarative](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/object-management-kubectl/declarative-config/)) configuration files that are checked in and versioned in a code repo than with [imperative commands](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/object-management-kubectl/imperative-command/).

Comment: The value of ``$HOSTNAME`` when a normal deployment config is used, will be the name of the pod. When you scale a pod, the name is obviously different for each instance, further it changes if a pod dies and is replaced. So updating the deployment config after the fact wouldn't help, especially since the act of changing the deployment config would results in a new deployment and so the pod names will change.

Comment: Executing `oc new-app -e  DASHBOARD_PROTOCOL=http ... grafana/grafana:5.2.1` will create few objects - an image stream, service...and a DeploymentConfig (dc) named "grafana", no? The dc will contain all the `-e` env vars from the `oc new-app` command. Edit/patch the dc to set the `DASHBOARD_HOSTNAME` env var using the Downward API (link to the docs given in the answer). The change will then apply to any new pods created from that dc.

Comment: Sorry, missed the specificity of mentioning downward API. Having to patch that after the fact isn't as convenient, so best to use a resource file/template for creating deployment if going to do that.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton no problem. Yes - as I mentioned in my answer, I like declarative configuration files (like OpenShift templates or resource files) better compared to "imperative commands".